# How to create new LOB in Guidewire?

Tags: guidewire

As i refer few documents related to new LOB creation,found we need to

1. Added new LOB as a typecode to into InstalledPolicyLine.ttx
2. Created an entity for new LOB and implemented few ImplementsEntity and ImplementsInterface,foreignkey to AutoNumbSequence entity.
3. Created a new class and extending AbstractPolicyLineMethodsImpl(for PolicyLineMethods).
4. Created new class for coverables for that implements CoverableAdapter.
   etc..

After all that i can able to see newPolicyLineMethod in the ProductModel. Is this approach or do i need to follow any other approaches.Guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from GW suite v8 you use Product Designer to build your product model.

You run Product Designer from

*(PC Root)/productdesigner/bin/launchPD(.bat)*

default user/pass is *su/gwgw* when you access it under http://localhost:8780

There you are able to customize your product model on the general level.
If you want to add some custom behaviour, then of course you'd need to add a variable amount of Gosu code to reach your business goal.

But anyway, in v8+, you don't need to start with tinkering with ttx. files.